# React: Copy and Paste the content of table's row to another don't overwrite the altready edited values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, configuration, copy-paste

I have been stuck for quite a while in a problem about copy and pasting of line in a table.
I am working on a web configurator app that need to display and handle loads of parameters.
Very often, I have to display a list of group of parameters which can be a lot of parameters to handle (For example: a list of 32 groups of 22 parameters making a total of 704 parameters to handle).

I have made a custom Table component in order to display them in rows and to directly modify the value of the parameters by displaying them in fields (text input...).
But the user was forced to edit the parameters's value one by one so I wanted to **add a feature to copy and paste the content of a row A in the table and to paste in an another row B.**
This is where it started to show some weird behaviors.

Here is the link to a reproductible demo of the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/fields-bug-9llgnc

To copy the content of a row you need to click on the furthest left cell in the RowName column of the row (Row 1) then hit **Crtl + C**
Next you select another row (Row 2) by clicking on it's furthest left cell and hit **Crtl + V**.
Usually it should paste the content of the row A into a row B, unless you follow theses steps in the demo:

1. Paste the content of Row 1 and paste it into Row 2
2. Edit the first field (last name) of Row 2
3. Repeat Step 1

You will see the value of the first field of Row 2 didn't get updated despite the paste.
**I can't overwrite the value of a field by pasting if I already have pasted it before and edited it's value after.**

I have tried several things, setting a useEffect reacting to the value prop change in order to change the useState but sometime the prop change never trigger the useEffect. I tried to set a custom hook to store the previous data of the value prop in order to compare with the new one and trigger an update but the useRef does reset it's value instead of persisting trough rerender.

I have no idea what could be the cause of my problem.
I'd have to copy and paste any content from one line into another, whatever content I'd edited before.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.